rtw89_8852ae on Ubuntu 24.04 LTS problems with wifi connection for HP Envy X360 (no firmware displayed)
Any possibility to upgrade Realtek driver?
sudo lshw -C network
  *-network                
       description: Wireless interface
       product: RTL8852AE 802.11ax PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       logical name: wlo1
       version: 00
       serial: a8:93:4a:3b:96:43
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtw89_8852ae driverversion=6.8.0-44-generic firmware=N/A ip=192.168.100.27 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:97 ioport:2000(size=256) memory:d0800000-d08fffff
